# Parse html table using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a train schedule table from SEPTA train (Pennsyvania Train). So far I am able to get the correct table, but when I try to loop 
thought the table values I always get a empty variable no matter what I look for: TD/TR/Text.

What I am trying to do is get the: Scheduled Time, Estimated Time and Arrival Time from Station name. I try to search the stop name: 'Malvern' and get the schedule time.

This is how I got the main table:

```
//// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://trainview.septa.org/550');
$table = $html->find('table#scheduletable');

foreach($table as $MainTable)
{ 
echo $MainTable;              
}   
?>
```

Ok, now I have my table. If I try to do any ForEach using $table, I get a blank page (probably some PHP exception).

Here is what I have been trying to do without any success:

```
foreach($table->find('td') as $td) {
 If($td == "Malvern") } // Found my row?

foreach($table->find('Malvern') as $td) {
    }

foreach($table->find('td td') as $td) {
    }

// Can I do this to get the TD values?
$table->find('td',0)->innertext // Station
$table->find('td',1)->innertext // Scheduled Time
$table->find('td',2)->innertext // Estimated Time
$table->find('td',3)->innertext // Arrival Time
```

This is how the table is formatted (HTML):

```
    <table class="taglist" id="scheduletable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#c1dcfa" colspan="6"> <h2>
        <div style="text-align: center;">Schedule for Train # 550 <br>
          May 11, 2015 </div>
      </h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#aaeeee">
      <th width="25%">Station</th>
      <th width="5%"> </th>
      <th><center>
        Scheduled Time
      </center></th>
      <th><center>
        Estimated Time
      </center></th>
      <th><center>
        Arrival Time
      </center></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thorndale</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:10 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:13 am</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Whitford</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:22 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:24 am</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Downingtown</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:17 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12:00 am</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Exton</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:24 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:26 am</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Malvern</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:30 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:32 am</td>
    <tr>
      <td>Paoli</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:34 am</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>10:38 am</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am reading all the HTML parser topics and I still cant figure out what is my problem here :(

Comment: part of your problem is that the times are not sub-nodes of your station name.   can you try an xpath where you just search for `//td`?  that should at least get you all of those.